# SED invalid command code for JSON response

Tags: regex, macos, sed, terminal

I am trying to get a value from a JSON from my local server (https://regex101.com/r/qeGcGu/1) on a headless mac mini (catalina), via sed. However, with the sed command I'd expect to work:

```
usr@mcMini  ~/Documents/qBitTorrent cat /tmp/json.out | sed -i.bak '"hash":"(.*?)"'
sed: 1: ""hash":"(.*?)"": invalid command code "
usr@mcMini  ~/Documents/qBitTorrent cat /tmp/json.out | sed -i.bak '\"hash\":\"(.*?)\"'
sed: 1: "\"hash\":\"(.*?)\"": unterminated regular expression
usr@mcMini  ~/Documents/qBitTorrent cat /tmp/json.out | sed -i '' '\"hash\":\"(.*?)\"'
sed: 1: "\"hash\":\"(.*?)\"": unterminated regular expression
usr@mcMini  ~/Documents/qBitTorrent cat /tmp/json.out | sed -i '' '"hash":"(.*?)"'
sed: 1: ""hash":"(.*?)"": invalid command code "
```

The file that I am trying to get the string from is a raw json.

```
[{"added_on":1587102956,"amount_left":0,"auto_tmm":false,"availability":-1,"category":"radarr","completed":1218638934,"completion_on":1587108704,"dl_limit":-1,"dlspeed":0,"downloaded":1220894674,"downloaded_session":0,"eta":8640000,"f_l_piece_prio":false,"force_start":true,"hash":"87802183fc647548ec6efe18feb16149522f6aa0","last_activity":1587119220,"magnet_uri":"magnet:?xt=urn:btih:87802183fc647548ec6efe18feb16149522f6aa0&dn=Fantasia%202000%20(1999)%20%5b1080p%5d%20%5bYTS.AG%5d&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3a6969%2fannounce&tr=udp%3a%2f%2f9.rarbg.com%3a2710%2fannounce&tr=udp%3a%2f%2fp4p.arenabg.com%3a1337&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3a6969&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.internetwarriors.net%3a1337&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.opentrackr.org%3a1337%2fannounce&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.zer0day.to%3a1337%2fannounce&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3a6969%2fannounce&tr=udp%3a%2f%2fcoppersurfer.tk%3a6969%2fannounce","max_ratio":-1,"max_seeding_time":-1,"name":"Fantasia 2000 (1999) [1080p] [YTS.AG]","num_complete":22,"num_incomplete":4,"num_leechs":0,"num_seeds":0,"priority":0,"progress":1,"ratio":0.1782183661159947,"ratio_limit":-2,"save_path":"/Volumes/1049/Media/","seeding_time_limit":-2,"seen_complete":1587118087,"seq_dl":false,"size":1218638934,"state":"forcedUP","super_seeding":false,"tags":"","time_active":13224,"total_size":1218638934,"tracker":"udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969/announce","up_limit":-1,"uploaded":217585854,"uploaded_session":128831791,"upspeed":0}]
```

Actually what I want to accomplish is to get the first 6 chars from hash:
"hash":"87802183fc647548ec6efe18feb16149522f6aa0"

In this case my desired value is **878021**

Could you please guide me in the correct direction?

Comment: Right. You may use `sed -n 's/.*"hash":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' /tmp/json.out`

Comment: How come you have this problem after getting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57026094/3832970)? The problem is almost the same.

Comment: Thank you for your time, it does the job. As you can see I am playing with this every pther year so I didnt take the time to analyze properly.

Comment: Note `sed` uses POSIX regex syntax, so you can't use `*?` / `+?` non-greedy quantifiers in `sed` regex. Also, remember about the delimiters, `sed` needs them when working with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -n 's/.*"hash":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' /tmp/json.out
```

Here, note that the file can be provided directly to the `sed` command, no need piping it with `cat`.

**How it works**

- `-n` - option that suppresses the default line output (by default, `sed` will output non-matching lines)
- `s/` - substitute command (we are replacing)
- `.*"hash":"\([^"]*\).*` - matches

  - `.*` - 0+ chars
  - `"hash":"` - `"hash":"` substring
  - `\([^"]*\)` - Group 1 (capturing group, `\1` is used in the replacement part to refer to this value) - any 0+ chars other than `"`
  - `.*` - 0+ chars
- `\1` - the replacement is Group 1 value (it is all that remains on the matching line)
- `p` - if there was a valid replacement print the result after replacement only.